# Is there a way to programmatically change the values of the manifest.json file in a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am currently working on a chrome extension that uses the popup page but it also changes the default new tab page and I want this feature to be optional i.e the user can decide if they want the extension to change their default new tab or not

I already tried using the `chrome.runtime.getManifest()` see [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getManifest) but it cn only be used for retrieving the values and not modifying.

Comment: No, it's not possible.